# Pattern matching over typed parameters in Scala

Tags: scala

Hey so I have the following ADT

```
 sealed trait MessageContext
 case class ThisMessageContext(...) extends MessageContext
 case class ThatMessageContext(...) extends MessageContext
```

and another class which is

```
 case class Message[+T <: MessageContext](...)
```

now I have this method

```
def doThisOrThat[T <: MessageContext](message: Message[T]) = message match {
    case mThis: Message[ThisMessageContext] = goThisWay(mThis)
    case mThat: Message[ThatMessageContext] = goThatWay(mThat)
}

private def goThisWay(msg: Message[ThisMessageContext]) = { // Some logic here}

private def goThatWay(msg: Message[ThatMessageContext]) = { // Some logic here}
```

Now I expect that for Message[ThatMessageContext] I am supposed to goThatWay but its evaluating to the first one. In fact due to type erasure its always hitting the first case no matter what I throw at it.

Is there a way to circumvent the type erasure here. AFAIK ClassTag is something I can use, but I do not how that works exactly. Also I do not like the idea of boxing the input.

Comment: Instead of pattern matching on the type parameter, you could match on a value of your message which is the context.

Comment: @Lus Miguel, yes I can but I cannot pass that forward to gotThis or thatWay. Their arugments are specific impls of Message[T].

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yep that works. Thanks.